# Assignment of NMR peaks of polystyrene

Tags: experimental-chemistry, polymers, nmr-spectroscopy

I’m having trouble identifying the peak around 3,75 ppm in the 1H-NMR spectrum of polystyrene measured at 400 Hz in CDCl3. Could someone please provide their perspective on it? I see it appear in a lot of polystyrene spectra but never know what it could be caused by. Thanks in advance!

[image: NMR of polystyrene (1)]

[image: NMR of polystyrene (2) this time without bromine as an end group]

Comment: Maybe it's from terminal groups.

Comment: I thought so too, just a bit confused which ones, and why would those peaks be so shifted.

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple causes of this kind of trace impurity in a 1H-NMR spectrum. For example trace solvents.

What I think is the most likely cause (it depends on the synthesis used), is that this peak is caused by a trace initiator or trace terminating agent. For example a brominated alkene chain.

I wouldn't worry about it too much as the integral is very small.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your answer.